# why is my content type showing up as image/2 should be image/jpeg

Tags: content-type

http://www.thomasnet.com/articles/hardware/fastener-threads

this image when viewing the requests with firebug in the net panel shows image/2 any idea why this would be set this way on the server side?

Comment: Is this your site?  If so, can you show the server code for the image?

Comment: The answer depends on the way the web server is configured.  Without that information, we can't help you.

Answer (score 2):

It's the only image being read from the 'articles/image/' folder (The rest come from the /images/images/' folder)

It's also the only image on the page which has a content-type at all.

And it's also the only image not cached.

My guess is that your web server is set to send certain header values based on directory.